# How to filter only specified type in class dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#, dynamic, endianness

My English skill is poor because I'm not a native English speaker.
please understand.

I will tell you about what I want detailly.
I created a class below

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public class TestClassForNetwork
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 11), JsonIgnore]
        public byte[] field1;

        public short field2;
        public short field3;
        public short field4;
    }
```

As you know, when deserializing or serializing, I pay attention to converting to a specified endian. so I added the below code.

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public class TestClassForNetwork
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 11), JsonIgnore]
        public byte[] field1;

        public short field2;
        public short field3;
        public short field4;

        public void ToHostOrder()
        {
            if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) return;

            field2 = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(field2);
            field3 = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(field3);
            field4 = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(field4);
        }

        public void ToNetworkOrder()
        {
            if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) return;

            field2 = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(field2);
            field3 = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(field3);
            field4 = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(field4);
        }
    }
```

Here, I thought if it is added the field that has more 2byte, I have to modify ToHostOrder and ToNetworkOrder functions. and this will increase the cost of maintenance.

So I thought the idea was as below.

```
        public void ToHostOrder()
        {
            if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) return;

            // filtering only short type in this class.
            FieldInfo[] shortFields;
            
            foreach(var shortField in shortFields)
                shortField = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(shortField);

            // filtering only int type in this class.
            FieldInfo[] intFields;

            foreach(var intField in intFields)
                intField = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(intField);
        }

        public void ToNetworkOrder()
        {
            if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) return;

            // filtering only short type in this class.
            FieldInfo[] shortFields;
            
            foreach(var shortField in shortFields)
                shortField = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(shortField);

            // filtering only int type in this class.
            FieldInfo[] intFields;

            foreach(var intField in intFields)
                intField = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(intField);
        }
```

This idea seems to be poor if the count of fields in class is small because the readability is poor but I think this idea will decrease the cost of maintenance if the count of field is bigger because it is no need to worry to convert to a specified endian.

Could someone tell me how to realize this idea?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using `System.Reflection` and getting all fields of a `short` type, and then using `GetValue` and `SetValue` to get and set the respective fields

In the constructor I set a List of all the fields, so it's only used once. Using `System.Linq`'s `Where` makes sure we only get fields of `short` type

```
    public TestClassForNetwork()
    {
        shortFields = this.GetType().GetFields().Where(field => field.FieldType == typeof(short)).ToList();
    }
    public List<FieldInfo> shortFields = new List<FieldInfo>();
```

Taking the same sample fields you have

```
    public byte[] field1;
    public short field2;
    public short field3;
    public short field4;
```

You can implement `ToHostOrder` and `ToNetworkOrder` like this

```
    public void ToHostOrder()
    {
        if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) return;

        foreach (var shortField in shortFields)
        {
            shortField.SetValue(this, IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder((short)shortField.GetValue(this)));
        }

    }

    public void ToNetworkOrder()
    {
        if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) return;

        foreach (var shortField in shortFields)
        {
            shortField.SetValue(this, IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder((short)shortField.GetValue(this)));
        }
    }
```

Going forward, you should only need to add new `short` fields in your class, for it to be implemented in the methods

Comment: I knew about Reflection but  I didn't know it can filter with FieldType. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can use [MemoryPack](https://github.com/Cysharp/MemoryPack) library and it can do it for you amazingly with higher performance and code readability.

- It doesn't use reflection and all of the stuff is being generated in compile time.
- It handles endian and other OS/CPU architecture stuff
- It is being maintained by a strong open-source community
- It's performance is 50X better than Json or ProtoBuff serialization

Comment: I think this library is amazing I will phase in this in my project. thank you for the good information.